# Percorrer linhas de uma dataTable do javaEE, jsf2 e Primefaces com as setas do Teclado?

Tags: ajax, jsf, hibernate, primefaces, java-ee

Encontrei esse código na internet, mas parte dele foi descontinuado

**xhtml:**

```
<p:hotkey bind="down" update=":testform:tabletest" action="#{aBean.moveDown()}" />
```

**aBean:**

```
public void moveDown() {   
  FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  DataTable table = (DataTable)ComponentUtils.findComponent(facesContext.getViewRoot(), "tabletest"); // obtem componente da tabela
  List<City> cl = (List<City>) table.getValue(); // obtem lista de elementos da tabela
  String p_code = selected.getPCode(); // obtém código único do elemento selecionado
  for(int i=0;i<cl.size();i++){ // itera toda a lista de valores
     if(p_code.equalsIgnoreCase(cl.get(i).getPCode())){ // verifica o elemento selecionado é o mesmo da iteração
        if(i==cl.size()-1){
           selected= cl.get(0); // caso seja o último item da lista, mantém ele mesmo selecionado
        }else{
           selected = cl.get(i+1); // caso contrário ele seta a seleção para a linha de baixo
        }
        break;
     }
   }
}
```

- `selected`: Linha selecionada
- `getPCode()`: Captura valor único do elemento da lista (algum ID por exemplo)

  Alguém teria algo parecido ou atual?

Comment: Essse é componente do primeFaces ,<p:hotkey bind="down" update=":testform:tabletest" action="#{aBean.moveDown()}" />

Answer (score 0):

O codigo erra Asim.

```
<p:dataTable id="tabelaBancos" paginator="true"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
        value="#{lancamentoTributoCdgBean.listaBancos}" var="item"
        paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="flase"
        style="margin-top: 5px;" rows="5">
```

Então Ficou assim:

```html
<p:dataTable id="tabelaBancos" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="2500"
  value="#{lancamentoTributoCdgBean.listaBancos}" var="item"
  style="margin-top: 5px;">
```